# Using Greasemonkey Scripts without Greasemonkey

Tags: linux, firefox, script, greasemonkey

I'm running Firefox in Linux x86_64. I'm wondering if it is possible to use the Greasemonkey scripts without using Greasemonkey. If the source of the scripts are available, is it possible to use them without even installing Greasemonkey?

Answer (score 2):

**IF** the script doesn't use [`GM_` functions](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Category:API_Reference)**, you can *usually* convert it to a [bookmarklet](https://superuser.com/tags/bookmarklet/info) and run it that way.

If the script uses the `@require` directive, then you must manually fetch the indicated file(s) and paste them into your bookmarklet.

[Here is an online tool to help convert javascript code to bookmarklets.](http://chriszarate.github.io/bookmarkleter/)

**You can also paste the javascript code into Firefox's console** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>), and run it that way.  The same restrictions, as with bookmarklets, apply.

---

** But there is [a limited-functionality shim that you can use to partially replace some `GM_` functions](https://web.archive.org/web/20121021232636/http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/145813).